# If $B\unlhd A$ and $[A : B] = 4$, prove that for every $x, y \in A$, $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in B.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

If we have $B$ a normal subgroup of a group $A$ and $[A : B] = 4$, I'm asked to prove that for every $x, y \in A$,  $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in B.$

I was thinking about using that $x^{4}$ is in $B$ and start from there but I'm stuck.

Any hints?

Comment: Hint: show the quotient group is Abelian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $B$ is normal in $A$, for every $x,y\in A$: $$BxBy=Bxy \tag1$$
On the other hand, since the quotient group is Abelian: $$BxBy=ByBx \tag2$$
But again by the normality of $B$: $$ByBx=Byx \tag3$$
Now go through $(1)$ to $(3)$, thus getting: $$Bxy=Byx$$
whence: $$Bxy(yx)^{-1}=B$$
and finally: $$xy(yx)^{-1}\in B$$

Answer (score 1):

The quotient group $A/B$ has order $4$.  There are only $2$ possibilities,  $\Bbb Z_4$ or $\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2$.

Thus the quotient is abelian.   Therefore $A'\le B$.